# How to Force Split Decision Tree in R

Tags: r, cart, rpart

Is there any ways that a user can force split the decision tree in R ?

I just think when building decision tree, we may need expert judgement in order to obtain the final model.  As far as I know, `prp(tree_model, snip = T)` in R can be used to interactive pruning the tree.